# how to regenerate webp et-pb-portfolio-image

Tags: images, thumbnails

How to regenerate webp? I problem not generate format webp : et-pb-portfolio-image: 400×284 pixels

```
   <img width="1" height="1" src="https://www.test.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/test.webp" class="attachment-et-pb-portfolio-image size-et-pb-portfolio-image" alt="test">
```

webp code in **functions.php**:

```
add_filter( 'wp_check_filetype_and_ext', 'wpse_file_and_ext_webp', 10, 4 );
function wpse_file_and_ext_webp( $types, $file, $filename, $mimes ) {
    if ( false !== strpos( $filename, '.webp' ) ) {
        $types['ext'] = 'webp';
        $types['type'] = 'image/webp';
    }

    return $types;
}

add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'wpse_mime_types_webp' );
function wpse_mime_types_webp( $mimes ) {
    $mimes['webp'] = 'image/webp';

  return $mimes;
}
```

Comment: Your code will let you upload .webp files but there's no code there to automatically regenerate them for you. Is that what you wanted to do - to automatically generate .webp versions of all of your images? On upload, or for all existing images too?

Comment: how to add automatically regenerate webp file?

Comment: Just use this plugin to automatic Webp conversion and jpeg/png optimization (for unsupported webp browsers):
https://wordpress.org/plugins/optipic/